# Error: Post "https://localhost:7053/participation/v1/channels": EOF Channel creation failed

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric2.2

I am trying to execute the test network on hyperledger Fabric.

I have installed the following prerequisites:

- curl version 7.68.0
- docker version 20.10.12
- docker-compose version 1.25.0
- go version 1.13.8
- node version 10.19.0
- npm version 6.14.4
- python version (3.8.10 and 2.7.18)

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

In the folder fabric-sample/test-network: I run

```
./network.sh down
```

and then  `./network.sh up`

then I tested

```
docker ps-a
```

It shows 2 fabric-peers and one orderer.

Now I'm trying to create a channel with `./network.sh createChannel` but I got this error how to solve it??

`Error: Post "https://localhost:7053/participation/v1/channels": EOF Channel creation failed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you having the same version of fabric docker images, fabric binaries and fabric samples. Checkout to specific [tags](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tags) in fabric samples repo if required. Latest version of fabric works with the main branch of samples.